# Automatically log in on another website at the click of a button - cURL or Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, curl

I would like to make a button on my website that automatically logs me in on another website. I recon I can use either Javascript/jQuery or PHP/cURL to do this.

Which is the best way to go?

Comment: PHP/curl won't do it. Any cookies sent from the other site will be going through your server and show as ORIGINATING from your server. It is not possible for curl to set a cookie in your browser in such a way that the browser things it came from the other server.

Comment: Am I not able to pass along the cookie from my server to the user clicking the button?

Comment: yes, you can, but the browser will see the cookie coming from YOUR server, not the other site's.

Comment: Ok. How about client side, then? :S

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but one thing I have done in the past is to mimic the login form on the site you want to log in to. 
For example lets say you want to log in to 'example.com'. In the source code for the login page of 'example.com' you will find the html code for the login form.

Example

```
<form name="blabla" action="action.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="sumbit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Create a form on your site similar to the one you find in 'example.com'. If you want you can even hide the fields, include values to make it a one button login. The trick is making sure that the action has the actual url. For example if the form says 'action.php' for 'example.com' you would put 'http://example.com/action.php'

Example

```
<form name="blabla" action="http://example.com/action.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="testuser" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="testpass" />
    <input type="sumbit" value="Login" />
<form>
```

This will log you in to the site in most cases. If you don't want to leave your own site you can set a 'target' for the form to an iframe or something.

Comment: Tried this but I get an error. I think it's because I don't have the right __EVENTTARGET __EVENTARGUMENT __VIEWSTATE __EVENTVALIDATION arguments - it's an aspx site.

Comment: Mind if I take a look at the target site? I might be able to help.

Comment: I'll take a look and get back to you asap.

Comment: Mike, did you forget? Hehe. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may use either remote javascript or iFrame. Find more details here: http://kuza55.blogspot.com/2007/06/building-secure-single-sign-on-systems.html

Also checkout google's approach named SAML: http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the website is. JavaScript and jQuery alone cannot be used due to the cross-domain policy. You could perhaps use a combination of cURL and AJAX to achieve something similar.

I think you might need to provide a little more information about the site, and exactly why you'd want to do this...